# Is that possible to have two transaction types = required_new in a stateless object?

Tags: java, transactions, ejb, jta

Kindly see the pseudo-code below.

```
Java method A(){

  Java method B(){}

}
```

This is a snippet of Java EJB application. The application is using JTA transactions.

I would like to know is that possible to have method A and B declared as transaction_type = requires_new.

Frankly, I could hardly see any online tutorial allows two requires_new transaction type in a stateless object. What I see the most is method A declared as required and method B declared as requires_new.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many methods marked with Requires_New in the stateless session bean as you like. However you have to be aware that new transaction will be only created when that method is called by the ejb client, not internally from the other bean method. So if you wanted to call from A method, B method in hope to create new transaction, that is not going to happen regardless of transaction attributes. You would have to call it via bean interface (either put that method in the other bean, or lookup same bean again and call that method via interface not internally)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Requires_New on both methodA and methodB then whats the purpose of a Transaction.  Because basically you are creating a new transaction for both the methods. Which is as good as running them in isolation.
Use [NotSupported](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncih/index.html) attribute if you just want to exclude a method from a transaction.

You have seen methods with RequiresNew and Required attribute, because in a transaction the transaction is started on first method call with Requires_New and then that transaction is utilized by the other method using Required.

Comment: The reason I apply transaction type = requires_new for both methods is because I hope method B is committed before continue running method A (Of course method A also need to be committed later) If anything happen on method A after running method B, the stuff in method B won't roll back.